# Combinatorics: Choose 3 questions from 12 (3 Sets of 4 questions)

Tags: combinatorics

There are 3 sets of questions with each set having 4 questions, therefore, total of 12 questions.

- Set A = A1,A2,A3,A4
- Set B = B1,B2,B3,B4
- Set C = C1,C2,C3,C4
- Q1) How many ways to answer 6 questions if we select 0 questions from
  one of the sets?
- Q2) How many ways to answer 6 questions if we select 1 question from
  one of the sets?

The answer given for (Q1) is =
Pick a section and choose 0 questions * Pick 6 questions from remaining 8 questions = **3C1 * 4C0 * 8C6**

However, this method does not give the correct answer for (Q2). ie. **3C1 * 4C1 * 8C5**  is not correct. I have found out this because I enumerated the combinations of choosing 6 questions as described in (Q2) which were (1,1,4), (1,2,3) and then calculating the question selection combinations for each. [ 4C1 * 4C1 * 4C4 * 3!/2! + 4C1 * 4C2 * 4C3 * 3! = 48 + 576 = 624

Does this mean that the method used in (Q1) above is not correct even though it gave the correct answer in that occasion?

Comment: Thanks @Math Lover. I corrected the question.

Answer (score 3):

If the interpretation of the second question is that we can have *exactly* one question  from one of the sets or *exactly* one question each from two different sets, then $624$ is the right answer.

$ \displaystyle 3 \cdot 4 \cdot{8 \choose 5}$ does not give correct answer for the second question as it double counts cases when there is one question each from two sets and all four from the last set.

So the answer should rather be,

$ \displaystyle 3 \cdot 4 \cdot{8 \choose 5} - 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 4 = 624$

$3 \cdot 4 \cdot 4$ is the number of ways of choosing $2$ sets and a question each from both sets. We pick all questions from the last set.

If the interpretation of the second question is that we can have one question from *exactly* one set, the answer should be,

$ \displaystyle 3 \cdot 4 \cdot{8 \choose 5} - 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 4$

as we subtract *twice* the cases where $1$ question each was chosen from two different sets (as they were double counted).

OR rewrite as,

$ \displaystyle 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 2 \cdot {4 \choose 3} {4 \choose 2}$

We choose a set with $1$ question and a question from the set and then choose $2$ and $3$ questions from remaining two sets.

Comment: Will meet when brain unscrambles after the Olympics :) +1

Comment: Yes I can understand :)

Comment: @math-lover, How do you **detect** (or forecast) that there will be duplicates in 3C1 * 4C1 * 8C5 ? Is there a pattern/clue/hint that you look for,  that can indicate that the calculation will include "duplicates"?

Comment: Say you choose one question from set A. Now using $8C5$, you select $5$ questions from set B and C but it is any $5$ questions out of $8$ so will include $4$ questions from set B and $1$ question from set C and also $1$ question from set B and $4$ from set C. But for example, when choose set B as part of $3C1$ and select $1$ question, you again count cases where there is  $1$ question each from both set A and B.

Comment: The clue here is that I am selecting a set with one question but $8C5$ also includes cases where there will be one question from one of the remaining two sets. That suggests there will be overcounting.